# Visualize file without download it minio

Tags: minio

I'm using Minio to store files, and I need to visualize some of this files from my browser without download it.
I used this piece of code, however it downloads the file unfortunately.

> minioClient.getObjectUrl(bucketName, ObjectName)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding [MinIO doc](https://docs.min.io/docs/java-client-api-reference.html#getPresignedObjectUrl), we can get stored object url, and for that I've used this piece of code :

```
// Get presigned URL of an object for HTTP method, expiry time and custom request parameters.
    Map<String, String> reqParams = new HashMap<>();
            reqParams.put("response-content-type", "application/pdf"); //very helpfull to preview pdf from browser
            return minioClient.getPresignedObjectUrl(Method.GET,bucketName,objectName,expiryTime,reqParams);
```

Comment: it gives url when we also download image but not actually do what answer was about

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem. If we do get the PresignedObjectUrl, it is required more additional parameters to view the file.